# Is there such a thing as a unique prediction/guess?

Tags: events, category

Are there predictions that are truly unique? Is uniqueness subjective or objective? What makes a prediction unique? Is the answer to this different from the general question of “what makes an event unique?”?

If I come across a person guessing a number in my head, I would not find it unique. This is because others have done the same. If someone predicts the name of a person who will die tomorrow, I will find this suspicious. I may even find it surprising. And yet, I would not find it unique since I can easily think of others doing this atleast at one other point in history.

On the contrary, imagine I come across a rock in a forest and for whatever reason decide to guess its latitude and also broadcast it on a video. Suppose I have no prior knowledge of latitudes in the current area except that it ranges from -90 to 90. I guess it correctly to the nearest integer. Something about this prediction, or rather guess, seems unique. It is not just the fact that it was successful. It feels unique to me since it is hard to imagine anyone else ever deciding to guess the latitude of an object especially in a verifiable, public way. There were no other “failed attempts” of this prediction. Does this mean that this kind of prediction is truly unique?

Something about the uniqueness judgement here seems objective in the sense that I can imagine a lot of people sharing this and finding this event to be at the very least weird. But because there seems to be no apriori reason solidly demonstrating this, and because I cannot test this without talking to other people, I can’t know for sure.

So in summary, what makes a prediction, and perhaps more generally, an event unique?

Comment: Events are like numbers, in a line they occur and every point in the line is an event. If someone calls 0,3 periodic to 1/3 he is just using another name to call the same. Let apart the discussion of naming the events, focus on the event itself. If two events happen in the same time and same space, they are the same event. So, you guessing the number 1/3 and your friend guessing the same number can't be the same event. That's all

Comment: Any prediction is unique in some sense (e.g. _this is the only 2596th prediction_). It all depends on how you group them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the following is entirely relevant to your question (it's at least peripherally relevant, since any given thing is peripherally relevant to everything else), [but](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sufficient-reason/#PSRContPhil):

> Implications for the [principle of sufficient reason] might also be discerned in recent discussions of *surprisingness* or *strikingness*, (although such implications are not typically stated explicitly). These discussions, which cut across such diverse subfields as epistemology, philosophy of science, metaethics, and philosophy of religion, have their origin in Paul Horwich’s observation that there is an intuitive difference between an event or fact being *unlikely* and its being *surprising* (Horwich 1982). For example, it is equally unlikely that, on a given occasion, a monkey typing randomly on a typewriter will type the string ‘sdlek93 91’ and that it will type ‘I want a banana.’ But although the probabilities of both events are the same, the latter string is surprising in a way that the former is not. The difference between surprising events or facts and unlikely fact is sometimes thought to map onto the distinction between events or facts that call out for explanation and those that do not. How can we account for the difference between the merely improbable—which some believe does not call out for explanation—and the surprising—which does?

I think the above might be relevant to your question, then, in that the uniqueness of a prediction might be correlated with whether it is surprising when such a prediction comes true. On the other hand, though, insofar as we are looking for the "uniformity of nature" in such contexts, we might think that our task is directed *away from* uniqueness (as irrepeatability): an event that can be predicted to happen once, and once only, then is an event that we are not expecting to happen again even if the only difference in prior conditions is position along some historical timeline.

Comment: Wow, that is a great find! Thank you. I too was wondering whether uniqueness is related to the surprisingness of an event or vice versa. I don’t seem to understand your last point about the task being directed away from uniqueness. Do you mind expanding a bit more on that?

Comment: @thinkingman I'm thinking that a general law would apply to multiple particulars, and what is common to the particulars is what is regulated by the law, rather than what is unique being so regulated/regulative. To be sure, though, there are theories of causation where individual objects' causal powers bear the explanatory weight, so there is room for uniquely calibrated causation.

Answer (score 0):

With few exceptions, every event or object can be considered unique. (The exceptions I have in mind are particles such as electrons, to which individual identity, apparently, cannot be meaningfully assigned.) Take the grains of sand on a beach- they are all unique in one sense, but not in another. Some events or objects are more unique than others in the sense that they appear to us to be truly one of a kind. That is because some differences between objects and events are more striking than others. To return to grains of sand, they might all be different in some way, but the differences are neither obvious nor important to us. If, on the other hand, you were to find a grain of sand which had been weathered to exactly resemble a miniature statue of Groucho Marx, you might consider that to be 'more unique' because as far as you know it stands out in a meaningful way from all the other unique grains of sand.

So one might claim that most things can be considered unique in some sense, but fewer things would seem to be unique in a way that was striking to the observer.

Comment: Do you think that one can meaningfully test how often certain kinds of events “feel” unique to certain people? Of course, I can simply list 100 different events and ask which one feels most unique to most people. But do you think their answers would be accurate or rather that their perception of uniqueness may be biased by other factors such as salience, personal relevance, etc. I suppose this may be more of a psychology question though but was interested in your thoughts

Comment: Good question. I think there would be a lot of random factors that affected how an individual might attribute different degrees of uniqueness to a thing or event, but my guess would be that if you were to perform a survey where you asked a large number of people to order the same list of events by degree of perceived uniqueness, there would be a correlation between their responses.

Comment: When you say correlation do you mean that their responses would be similar?